# How do I pass Properties from a CustomControl to it's UserControls in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, custom-controls

I currently have a problem with some `DependencyProperties` in my code. I made my own `Control` which is supposed to be used in many instances of my app. I was able to bind a boolean `DependencyProperty` and use it's value in the control itself. Now I need to bind a `Style` to it's children.

Here is how I want to bind the property:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="style" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <local:MyControl ButtonStyle="{StaticResource style}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The value will be set in MyControl.cs this way:

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonStyleProperty= DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ButtonStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }

    public Style ButtonStyle
    {
        get => (Style)GetValue(ButtonStyleProperty);
        set => SetValue(ButtonStyleProperty, value);
    }
}
```

The Generic.xaml of my custom control owns an `UserControl` which needs the `ButtonStyle`.
I'm trying to pass it in the Generic.xaml like this:

```
<controller:ControllerView ButtonStyle="{Binding ButtonStyle}"/>
```

Here is the code-behind for the `ControllerView`. For some reason the setter is never accessed.

```
public partial class ControllerView : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ButtonStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(ControllerView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public ControllerView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Style ButtonStyle
    {
        get => (Style)GetValue(ButtonStyleProperty);
        set => SetValue(ButtonStyleProperty, value);
    }
}
```

And it's supposed to be used in the ControllerView.xaml like this:

```
<Button Name="Button" Style="{Binding ButtonStyle}"
        Content="{Binding Text, Mode=OneTime}" Command="{Binding Command, Mode=OneTime}"
        Margin="1" FontSize="24">
```

If anyone could tell me why it doesn't work this way and maybe suggest a solution to my code or can tell me how one would normally do this, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Binding` will use the `DataContext` as source by default, from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.source?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> By default, bindings inherit the data context specified by the `DataContext` property, if one has been set.

Dependency properties are not part of the `DataContext`. They are defined on controls. You can use a [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=net-5.0) binding or in some cases an [`ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname?view=net-5.0) to refer to another control for binding.

If I understood your decription correctly, `MyControl` contains a `ControllerView` and its `ButtonStyle` property should be bound to the `ButtonStyle` property of the parent `MyControl`.

```
<controller:ControllerView ButtonStyle="{Binding ButtonStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}}}"/>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks a lot. I think I got confused because my MyControl has no DataContext set and it's DataContext was therefore the MyControl.cs so I was able to set my Properties as I have in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because your ControllerView is trying to reference its own data from the wrong DataContext.

I like the approach shown in this tutorial:

https://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html

Doing external binds to a UserControl's properties doesn't really work by default since that requires the use of two different DataContexts; if you try to bind assuming your default DataContext for your view then it won't work because the DataContext doesn't have any understanding of what is contained within your UserControl, and conversely if you try to just set the DataContext of the UserControl to itself then it won't have any understanding of the external data you're trying to pass in.

The solution is to set the control's DataContext to itself, but not immediately on the whole thing; instead nest it one level deep to your control's main containing panel. So if you had

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    //control contents go here
    </Grid>
<UserControl>
```

in that UserControl's code-behind you could enter

```
public UserControlName()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
}
```

and the end result is that you will be able to bind to this control using data from another DataContext, and then the control will use its own DataContext (now containing the bound data from the other DataContext) within itself.

If you cooked up some dependency properties for that UserControl, you can now easily reference them, as well; your `<controller:ControllerView ButtonStyle="{Binding ButtonStyle}"/>` line would work perfectly.